# how to rewrite my application url to my domain in AWS

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, amazon-s3

I have EC2 instance created in AWS the ip is for example `54.26.12.***`

I have my domain (mydomain.com) registered with S3bucket for this EC2 instance, Now this domain shows the index page provided by AWS.

Now `54.26.12.***` is available while hitting `mydomain.com` in browser.

In this instance, I deployed a war file to tomcat server and I am able to run this as `mydomain.com:8080/myAppUrl`.

I am looking for show this application url while hitting `mydomain.com` in browser.

I can put `.htaccess` file to rewrite urls. But in AWS I cant do that as it is not supported.

How do I rewrite in AWS to my app for my domain.

### Update

domain screen now
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a `A record` on your provider (route53, GoDadddy, NameCheap ...) to point `myapp.mydomain.com` on your ec2 instance.

On the ec2 instance you would need to run apache to listen on port 80 and forward to your app server the requests.

Otherwise you need to change your current `A record` on `domain.com` to point to your ec2 IP address and not the S3 bucket

Comment: Henri, Thanks for your answer. I added `A Record`(EC2 instance IP) in route53 for my domain. can you pls help what to do now. I cant understand the second point regarding Apache...

Comment: Here are the steps I did. https://amimoto-ami.com/2015/01/25/assigned-domain-route-53-setting-elastic-ip/... now my app runs in 8080 port with name "myapp". for example, `myip:8080/myapp`. How do I show this app home page, while hit my domain in browser?

Comment: make tomcat listening on port 80. open the `/conf/server.xml` and change from `<Connector .... port="8080" ....>` to `port="80"`

Comment: I changed tomcat port from 8080 to 80. Still I am getting the same page... updated question with that screen, pls take a look.

Comment: well you have apache running already listening on port 80 - so you can stop it if you make tomcat listening on port 80, or configure apache to forward request to tomcat.

Comment: Ok. I stopped Apache. Now my domain shows the tomcat home page as in my updated question. But,  I need to show my app for my domain. Now `mydomain - shows - tomcat homepage`.. how to show `mydomain-shows-tomcat homepage/myApp`... I attached screen shot of my domain in question. Pls take a look Henri. Thanks in advance.

Comment: move your app directly in `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT` (note I am not saying to create a new folder under ROOT but directly push your app files into ROOT .. or rename the current webapps/app folder to webapps/ROOT)

Comment: Thank you Henri, That fixed my issue completely... thanks again.